# Issues with using webcam, system freezes or gets unstable after some time

Tags: ubuntu, camera

I use my Logitech Streamcam with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and it does connect properly. I can use it in some applications, like skype, zoom and discord. But after some time (around 3 minutes) the cam won't turn on anymore and the system completely freezes or gets very unstable, until I unplug the webcam. Cheese and guvcview never worked, they detect the camera but just show a black screen.

`dmesg | grep uvcvideo` returns

```
...
[    4.684206] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Logitech StreamCam (046d:0893)
[    4.700237] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[14322.880477] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 9 on unit 11: -110 (exp. 5).
[15471.160277] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 9 on unit 11: -110 (exp. 5).
[15524.183921] uvcvideo: Failed to set UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
[15529.303890] uvcvideo: Failed to set UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
...
```

and `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` returns

```
Logitech StreamCam (usb-0000:02:00.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

and finally `lsusb -vvv` returns

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:0893 Logitech, Inc. Logitech StreamCam
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.20
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0893 
  bcdDevice            3.17
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
...
```

I'm using a Ryzen 2700x with an Asrock fatality x470 motherboard.

Comment: File a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I will do that. But it seems to work on most other devices with the same software, could I just be missing a driver or something?

Comment: *the system completely freezes or gets very unstable, until I unplug the webcam* - this strongly indicates an issue with the kernel which should be fixed.